# Get/Send element attributes onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the function:

```
function showSMSForm(tmpTo, tmpContent, candidateID) {
//do stuff
}
```

Can I call this from the following html and pass in the parameters from the caller:

```
<span candidateID="233" tmpTo="12345678" onclick="showSMSForm()"></span>
```

I know I can do this by changing the method and passing in `this` and finding the attributes via jQuery but I would prefer not to do this. Are there other options?

Comment: `<span onclick="showSMSForm('233', '12345678')"></span>` or similar?

Comment: _"I know I can do this by changing the method and passing in this and finding the attributes via jQuery but I would prefer not to do this."_  Why not?

Comment: Jason: variables are dynamically generated. j08691: I call the function in many places already + I am curious about alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get tag's attributes  by :

```
onclick="showSMSForm(this.attributes['tmpTo'].value)"
```

that will pass the attribute tmpTo value to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option I found without changing original method:

```
function showSMSForm(tmpTo, tmpContent, candidateID) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        showSMSForm($(arguments[0]).attr("tmpTo"), "", $(arguments[0]).attr("candidateid"));
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<span candidateID="233" tmpTo="12345678" onclick="showSMSForm(this)"></span>
```